# Conditional Loop with numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to implement the following simple condition with numpy arrays, but the output is wrong.

```
dt = 1.0
t = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, dt)
x = np.empty_like(t)
if np.where((t >=0) & (t < 3)):
    x = 2*t
else:
    x=4*t
```

I get the output below

```
array([0., 2., 4., 6., 8.])
```

But I am expecting

```
array([0., 2., 4., 12., 16.])
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Looking in the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for `np.where`:

> **Note**: When only condition is provided, this function is a shorthand for
> `np.asarray(condition).nonzero()`. Using `nonzero` directly should be
> preferred, as it behaves correctly for subclasses. The rest of this
> documentation covers only the case where all three arguments are
> provided.

Since you don't provide the `x` and `y` arguments, `where` acts like `nonzero`.
`nonzero` returns a `tuple` of `np.arrays`, which is truthy when converted to bool.  So your code ends up evaluating as:

```
if True:
    x = 2*t
```

Instead, you want to use:

```
x = np.where((t >= 0) & (t < 3), 2*t, 4*t)
```

Answer (score 2):

The usage of [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is different

```
dt = 1.0
t = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, dt)
x = np.empty_like(t)
x = np.where((t >= 0) & (t < 3), 2*t, 4*t)
x
```

Output

```
[ 0.,  2.,  4., 12., 16.]
```

Answer (score 2):

in your code the if statement is not necessary and causes the problem.

np.where() creates the condition therefore you do not need the if statement.

Here is a working example of your code with the output you want

```
dt = 1.0
t = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, dt)
x = np.empty_like(t)
np.where((t >=0) & (t < 3),2*t,4*t)
```

Comment: What is the best way to write this code if I have multiple if-then conditions since np.where  only allows 3 arguments? ```dt = 1.0
t = np.arange(0.0, 4.0, dt)
x = np.empty_like(t)
if ((t>=0.0).any()) & ((t<1.0).any()):
    x = 2*t
elif ((t>=1.0).any()) & ((t<2.0).any()):
    x = 3*t
elif ((t>=2.0).any()) & ((t<3.0).any()):
    x = 4*t
else:
    x = 5*t ```

Comment: Hi, you just need to chain the condition, like in Excel. 
`dt = 1.0
t = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, dt)
x = np.empty_like(t)
x = np.where((t >=0) & (t < 1),2*t,np.where((t >=1) & (t < 2),3*t,np.where((t >=2) & (t < 3),4*t,5*t)))`